# How to determine what features to use for regression or classification?

Tags: python, machine-learning, scikit-learn

Im working with CSV file, that has 12 columns. Ten columns are features and two columns represent the results. I made a couple of regression and classification models with Python's scikit-learn lib.

I found out that accuracy varies depending on which features I use and how many parameters I use.

Is there a way to determine what features to use for regression or classification, Is there are way to find out what are the best parameters for my model?

This is the simple code I wrote, it has 3 features and one result, how to determinate what are the best features to use (is it best to use `'par_1'` and `'par_2'` , or just `'par_2'`, `'par_1'` and `'par_3'` , `'par_2`' and `'par_3'` ...), is there a way to get the list of the best features?

```
import pandas as pd
from sklearn.linear_model import LinearRegression


dic = {'par_1': [10, 30, 11, 19, 28, 33, 23],
       'par_2': [1, 3, 1, 2, 3, 3, 2],
       'par_3': [15, 3, 16, 65, 24, 56, 13],
       'outcome': [101, 905, 182, 268, 646, 624, 465]}

df = pd.DataFrame(dic)

variables = df.iloc[:,:-1]
results = df.iloc[:,-1]

print(variables.shape)
print(results.shape)


reg = LinearRegression()
reg.fit(variables, results)

x = reg.predict([[18, 2, 21]])[0]
print(x)
```

Is it a way to get a list of features that I should use?

Comment: The search term you're missing is "principal component analysis", or simply "PCA".

Answer (score 2):

If by parameters, you mean features than there are a lot of options.

1. Feature Elimination: Sklearn has several methods for this. The model automatically removes features which are not providing relevant information. There are several types of methods so choose the one which best fits your needs.
2. Feature Reduction: You can use either PCA or SVD in this where the important information is extracted from the features and features are reduced. In PCA you will lose the original features.
3. Feature Selection / Correlation Test: This is a manual testing method where you can correlate the feature to the output column using various correlation test and choose features accordingly.

If by parameter you mean the models hyperparameters, then search sklearn's documentation for `GridSearchCV`.

Comment: scikit-learn has also a page about that: https://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/feature_selection.html

Comment: PCA for feature *reduction* should not be advised lightheartedly; there is **no** guarantee that the top principal components have more predictive power than the low-variance ones - see answer in [How can top principal components retain the predictive power on a dependent variable (or even lead to better predictions)?](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/141864/how-can-top-principal-components-retain-the-predictive-power-on-a-dependent-vari)

Comment: I done the research but I could  not find the answer. Is there a way to get the names of the featuresthat the best for my model?